# Grouping UITableView section with webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Hello guys i want to use section with webservice so if i group in webservice uirefresh every new data should be added a new section. can i group data with date or head_line easy thank you for helping

```
{
succeed: 1,
message: "succeed",
data: [
{
id: "1144",
date: "11.09.2013",
time: "16:20",
code: "AKGUV",
head_line: "content ",
news: "Lorem ipsum dolar",
news_id: "20130911162025",
company_id: "1979"
}, {
id: "1145",
date: "11.09.2013",
time: "16:20",
code: "AKGUV",
head_line: "content ",
news: "Lorem ipsum dolar",
news_id: "20130911162025",
company_id: "1979"
}, {
id: "1146",
date: "11.09.2013",
time: "16:20",
code: "AKGUV",
head_line: "content ",
news: "Lorem ipsum dolar",
news_id: "20130911162025",
company_id: "1979"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a grouped/sectioned tableView, your data likely needs to be a multidimensional array. Probably you'll want a NSMutableArray that you can create a new NSArray based on your parameters, and add that NSArray(s) to the NSMutableArray.

```
NSArray* array = [webserviceDictionary objectForKey:data];
[mutArray addObject:array];
```

Comment: do you have any sample for this i really need that

Comment: i am trying thank you so much.you say that i should make that every date if date exists add ns array if not i should create new one.

Comment: you can do that of course, and it depends how the data is: if all the dates of your section are the same, you only need to look at one item in that section, otherwise you'll have to iterate each item in the section or use NSSet maybe to optimize